# How to access widget class id from different class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Am trying to figure out how to make button in `ScreenTwo` class access a function found in `ScreenOne` class

This is hot-reload `main.kv` :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kaki.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import os

class MainApp(MDApp, App):
    DEBUG = 1 # set this to 0 make live app not working

    # *.kv files to watch
    KV_FILES = {
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "screens/screen.kv"), # state your screen kv file
       }
    
    # class to watch from *.py files
    CLASSES = {
        "Manager": "screens.screen",}     ##use this in case of using separate py file 
        ## in python file  Main>>  class to watch in python file
        ## screen>> python file name
    
    # class to watch from *.py files
    # auto reload path
    AUTORELOADER_PATHS = [
        (".", {"recursive": True}),
    ]

    def build_app(self):
        return Factory.Manager() ## change screen to manager
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

This is `screen.py` :

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen , ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen 

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    
    def change(self):
        ScreenTwo.ids.news_d_subject.text='hello'
        pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

This is `screen.kv` :

```
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<Manager>:
    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two

    ScreenThree:
        id: screen_three

<ScreenOne>:
    name: "screen1"
    MDIconButton:           
        icon:'home'
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = "screen2"     ## switch to the second screen
            root.change()        ## change header text in the second screen
        

<ScreenTwo>:
    name: "screen2"
    
    MDIconButton:               
        icon:'help-circle'
        on_release:root.manager.current = "screen1"         ## switch to the first screen

    MDLabel:
        id:news_d_header
        text:'header text'
                    
<ScreenThree>:
    name: "screen3"
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the properties of ScreenOne from within ScreenTwo, you can use:

`self.manager.get_screen('screen_one').<property_name>`